# How to add a string into an NSArray at particulap index?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray

```
NSInteger timeNum = time; 
NSMutableArray theResultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[theResultArray insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:timeNum] atIndex:rightIndex];
```

This is the way we do to insert NSInteger to array. How to i do it for NSString?

Answer (score 3):

It's easier because you don't have to encapsulate the integer:

```
[theResultArray insertObject:myNSString atIndex:rightIndex];
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

It's exactly the same:

```
NSString* myNSString = @"foo"; 
NSMutableArray theResultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[theResultArray insertObject:myNSString atIndex:rightIndex];
```

Be aware that if you try to insert an object in a position that doesn't exist (i.e. if rightIndex > [theResultArray count]), you will get an exception.  In the example above, the only legal value for rightIndex is 0 because the array is empty.